# Can I make Firefox ignore/interpret font sizes specified in pixels?

Tags: firefox, fonts, css

I have an 11.1" notebook display with 1366x768 resolution, which gives it a DPI of 141. I'm running GNOME and have configured the DPI. Everything works OK except web browsing - far too many websites specify their font sizes in pixels, which ends up with very small text on a high DPI display. My ideal solution would be for Firefox to interpret an absolute pixel size in terms of normal DPI and display it appropriately for my DPI (eg scale it by 141/96). Obviously this would cause problems on the occasion where graphics had been pixel-aligned with fonts in some way, but I imagine that would cause me far less of a headache than either reading minute text, or scaling the text manually each time.

Any suggestions?

TIA,

Andy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's a "minimum font size" setting in Firefox that should do the trick.

Go to Tools, Options, Content tab, then click the Advanced button in the Fonts and Colors section.  Then set the Minimum Font Size to something that's reasonable for your display.